# I am unable to install PyAudio

Tags: python, pip, pyaudio

I tried different ways to install **PyAudio** but nothing was possible... I saw the same Error everytime.
I saw someone else also had the same problem I read his question, I saw that everything was same in our question. But someone commented that you can download **VsCode C++ Build Tools,** but does anyone has any other way to solve my issue?
If yes please do that as soon as possible!!!

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\som\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Som\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-im6cqmmw\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Som\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-im6cqmmw\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Som\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-gtvpy8y6'
       cwd: C:\Users\Som\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-im6cqmmw\pyaudio\
  Complete output (9 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\som\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Som\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-im6cqmmw\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Som\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-im6cqmmw\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Som\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-d6mu781h\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\som\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\Som\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-im6cqmmw\pyaudio\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\som\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Som\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-im6cqmmw\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Som\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-im6cqmmw\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Som\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-d6mu781h\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\som\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard Python distribution from python.org, you can download a PyAudio wheel from Christoph Gohlke's unofficial [Python Extension Packages for Windows](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) repository. Once downloaded, in the command prompt or Powershell, go to the directory where you downloaded the `.whl` file and simply enter

```
pip install name_of_file_you_just_download.whl
```

obviously using the real name of the file.